# Depth First Search Possible Nodes

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to find a possible order in which the given graph nodes could be visited in performing the Depth First Search and Breadth First Search. Doing the Depth First search I got FACBDE and doing Breadth First Search I got FACDEB [Please Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7jlW.png)but I am not sure if this is the right answer. Could someone please check it and tell me of my answer is right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll waste no time by saying that your BFS and DFS answers do look correct.
I'm assuming that the nodes that are given are to be ordered lexicographically. Are you asking this question because you are confused by how each search method works?

Keep in mind that if you get confused, you can always think of BFS as level based search. So, search for all neighbors in respective order. And DFS is more brute forced search. I'd recommend memorizing the psuedo code for each of these search methods. It helps a bunch when your actually coding these things.

BFS:

- enqueue start node and mark as visited
- start loop
- find all neighbors and if not already visited mark as visited
- add new visited to queue
- search for goal
- dequeue ( pop first element off the queue )
- repeat...

DFS:

- add start node to stack

  - start loop
- find first encountered and unvisited neighbor
- mark as visited
- add to stack
- if no neighbors, pop stack
- repeat...

Comment: Yes, nodes should be in Alphabetical order. Could you please just check my answer because I did follow the same algorithm? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`DFS` is correct. `BFS` should be `FACEDB`.

When expanding `A`, the order should be `C`->`E`->`D` according to the edge number.